# Is there a way to know which Firefox tab prevents Windows from sleeping?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, sleep

Using the latest Firefox (90.0.2) in Windows 10 [powercfg](/questions/tagged/powercfg) shows:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /requests
>
> DISPLAY: None.
>
> SYSTEM: None.
>
> AWAYMODE: None.
>
> **EXECUTION: [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume5\..\firefox.exe non-display
> request**
>
> PERFBOOST: None.
>
> ACTIVELOCKSCREEN: None.

I refreshed all my tabs which got it fixed:

> EXECUTION: None.

But since refreshing my tabs lost me some forms, while none of my tabs played video or audio, can I know next time which tab caused it and why?

Comment: Maybe Firefox Task Manager shows something related to that

Comment: I don't see audio info there and its purpose is more about [what slows down Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/task-manager-tabs-or-extensions-are-slowing-firefox). While you might say what slows down also prevents sleep, I'd like a more direct way to know.